# groupby and orderby in web2py

Tags: python, web2py

I have three tables:

```
db.define_table('projects',Field('name'))
db.define_table('tests',
                Field('name'),
                Field('project',db.projects, notnull=True))
db.define_table('results',
                Field('test',db.tests, notnull=True),
                Field('status'),
                Field('started', 'datetime', writable=False))
```

I would like to have a list of projects with the number of passed and failed tests. A test is passed/failed, if the newest result has the status 'pass'. When there is no result for a test, the status should be None.

Comment: ...and your question is? What have you tried to achieve it?

Comment: How can I get a list of projects containing the number of passed and failed tests?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something procedural

```
for project_row in db(db.projects).select():
    numPassed = 0
    numFailed = 0
    numNull =0
    num = 0
    for test_row in db(db.tests.project==project_row).select():
        results=db(db.results.test==test_row).select(orderby=~db.results.started,
                                                       limitby=0)
        if len(results) == 0:
            numNull += 1
        elif results[0].status=="pass":
            numPassed +=1
        else:
            numFailed +=1
    print project_row.name, numPassed, numFailed, numNull
```

Comment: I hoped, there is a single select for it using groupby etc.